# I have a head, but not a body

Tags: riddle

I have a head, but not a body
I don't think but I go to the top
The fatter am I the faster I go Up
When I'm down, people are happy
but when I go up people are sad

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a head, but not a body.

> balloon looks like a head

I don't think but I go to the top.

> "top" here refers to higher altitude, not higher rank of any organisation or company, so balloon goes higher without thinkig

the fatter am I the faster I go Up.

> the more gas or air filled balloon looks fatter and it goes up faster

When I'm Down People are Happy but when I go up People are Sad.

> when the balloon is down people play with it and are happy but when it gets cut loose from the string that the perrson is holding then people don't like loosing a balloon

What am I?

> I am a Balloon